# Declare and insert a new table and insert new rows in the new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a little problem here.

I have to declare and create a new table from already existing table.

In the new table I have to insert new rows.

I am working on the following code where I am able to create a new table with new rows but the other rows are missing.

pls help me.

```
Declare @NOA table
(
[ID]    Varchar(256),
[Groupname] Varchar(256),
[Mis_Code]  Varchar(256),
[Caption]   Varchar(256),
[Amount]    Varchar(256),
[AverageBalance]    Varchar(256),
[Year]  Varchar(256),
[Period]    Varchar(256),
[Category]  Varchar(256),
[ProductCode]  Varchar(256),
[RevExp]    Varchar(256)
);
INSERT INTO @NOA
(ID,Groupname,  Mis_Code,Caption,Amount,AverageBalance,Year,Period,Category,ProductCode,RevExp)
 Select a.[ID],'Count of existing accounts',a.[Mis_Code],a.[Caption],
 (a.[Amount] - n.[Amount]),a.[AverageBalance],a.[Year],a.[Period],a.[Category],a.[ProductCode],a.[RevExp]
 FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductSummaryMetrics WHERE [Groupname] = 'Count of active accounts') a
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductSummaryMetrics WHERE [Groupname] = 'Count of new account opened (MTD)') n
    ON a.[Mis_Code] = n.[Mis_Code]
    select distinct Groupname from @NOA
```

with the above code 
I get the output as

```
Groupname 
--------------------------
Count of existing accounts
```

Where as I would like to get all the group names like this

```
Groupname 
--------------------------
Count of existing accounts 
Count of active accounts
Count of new account opened (MTD)
```

Comment: sql server or mysql? pick one

Comment: Why not both? Why not Zoidberg?

Comment: It isn't MySQL. Enclosing entities with `[..]` isn't allowed there

Comment: @AlmaDo it is sqlserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

Thank you.

It is as follows

```
Declare @NOA table
(
[ID]    int,
[Groupname] Varchar(500),
[Mis_Code]  Varchar(500),
[Caption]   Varchar(500),
[Amount]    Decimal(38,0),
[AverageBalance]    Decimal(38,6),
[Year]  int,
[Period]    int,
[Category]  Varchar(50),
[ProductCode]   Varchar(50),
[RevExp]    Decimal(38,6)
)
Insert into @NOA
(
[ID],
[Groupname],
[Mis_Code],
[Caption],
[Amount],
[AverageBalance],
[Year],
[Period],
[Category],
[ProductCode],
[RevExp]
)
(Select 
[ID],
[Groupname],
[Mis_Code],
[Caption],
[Amount],
[AverageBalance],
[Year],
[Period],
[Category],
[ProductCode],
[RevExp]
from [dbo].[ProductSummaryMetrics])

INSERT INTO @NOA
 (ID,Groupname, Mis_Code,Caption,Amount,AverageBalance,Year,Period,Category,ProductCode,RevExp)
 Select a.[ID],'Count of existing accounts',a.[Mis_Code],a.[Caption],
 (a.[Amount] - n.[Amount]),a.[AverageBalance],a.[Year],a.[Period],a.[Category],a.[ProductCode],a.[RevExp]
 FROM (SELECT * FROM @NOA WHERE [Groupname] = 'Count of active accounts') a
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM @NOA WHERE [Groupname] = 'Count of new account opened (MTD)') n
    ON (a.[Mis_Code] = n.[Mis_Code] and a.[Caption] = n.[Caption] and a.[Period] = n.[Period])
  select distinct Groupname from @NOA
```